# JavaScript heap out of memory in NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

i have node.js 7 installed.
i have this error:

```
$ npm search mongo npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient [..................] | : WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient <--- Last few GCs --->

[12455:0x23175c0]    73384 ms: Mark-sweep 1038.6 (1354.9) -> 1032.1 (1351.0) MB, 808.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested [12455:0x23175c0]    74196 ms: Mark-sweep 1032.1 (1351.0) ->
1031.9 (1314.0) MB, 811.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort gc  [12455:0x23175c0]    75024 ms: Mark-sweep 1031.9 (1314.0) -> 1031.9 (1307.0) MB, 828.2 /
0.0 ms  last resort gc 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1301816c0d11 <JS Object>
    1: fromString(aka fromString) [buffer.js:217] [pc=0xd2afa68dcae](this=0x130181604311 <undefined>,string=0x2c89d250c589 <Very long string[216148348]>,encoding=0x1301816c9921 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: from [buffer.js:114] [pc=0xd2afa691090](this=0x12c0d1a860b1 <JS Function Buffer (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1301816e2009)>,value=0x2c89d250c589 <Very long string[216148348]>,encodingOrOffset=0x1301816...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: node::Abort() [npm]  2: 0xf4e4cc [npm]  3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [npm]  4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [npm]  5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [npm]  6: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [npm]  7: v8::internal::String::Flatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [npm]  8: v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*, int, int*, int) const [npm]  9: node::StringBytes::Write(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long, v8::Local<v8::Value>, node::encoding, int*) [npm] 10: node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) [npm] 11: node::Buffer::CreateFromString(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [npm] 12: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [npm] 13: 0x7f1698 [npm] 14: 0x7f1a30 [npm] 15: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm] 16: 0xd2afa1063a7 Annullato (core dump creato)
```

i have 32GB of ram!
how can i resolve??

Comment: Are you using the newest version of NPM? - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12619

Comment: hi! i'm using versione 3.10.9!

Comment: this works: $ node --max-old-space-size=2048 /usr/bin/npm search mongo

Comment: You should also update your npm, seems like a similar, if not the same, issue was esolved in version 4

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your version of npm is outdated. Just `npm upgrade -g` to update npm to v4.x and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$ node --max-old-space-size=8192 $(which npm) search mongo` instead!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ran `"tsc -p . && node --max-old-space-size=4096 dist/src/index.js"` which did not work. Instead I had to move the `--max-old-space-size=4096` to the beginning before the `tsc -p`:
`"NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' tsc -p . &&  node dist/src/index.js"`